# I can't get my Drop Down menu show the <a> in two lines

Tags: html, css

This is my first ;-)

I've got a problem with my drop down menu. The text of my  is quite long and I would like to show it in two rather than in one line. I'm trying it for the last two days but couldn't make it work. I change the width to go for 1 line - but it doesn't look nice. I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something simple - but I can't see it.

I would appreciate any help a lot!

This is my code:

My HTML:

```
<ul class="supplier_top_link">
    <li>Category 1
        <ul class="supplier_1">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 2
        <ul class="supplier_1">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 3
        <ul class="supplier_2">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 4</a>
        <ul class="supplier_2">
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Very very very long Sub-Category 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another long Sub-Category 4 & Category 5</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 6</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Category 7</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Very long Sub-Category 8</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
.supplier_top_link {
  position    : relative;
  font-size   : 14px;
  font-weight : 400;
  z-index     : 3;
     }

.supplier_top_link li {
   position   : relative;
   display    : inline-block;
}

.supplier_top_link li ul {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 25px;
  display  : none;

}

.supplier_top_link li:hover ul {
  padding-top : 4px; 
  display     : block;
}

.supplier_top_link li ul li {
  position : relative;
  display  : block;
}

.supplier_top_link li ul li a {
  color      : #a6a6a6; 
  font-size  : 14px;
  display    : block;
  float      : left;
  background : #191919;
  border-top : 1px solid #333;
  width      : 230px !important;
  height:28px;
  min-height:28px;
  padding    : 0 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px; 
    -webkit-border-radius:0px; 
    border-radius:0px;
}

.supplier_top_link li ul li a:hover {
   color : white;
   border-top : 1px solid #ff6c00;
}

.supplier_1 li a {
    text-align:left;
    }

.supplier_2 {
    margin-left:-150px;
}

.supplier_2  a {
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:15px;
}
```

Comment: You must give more info. What do you mean by not nice?

Comment: Not sure i understand, you want the same size for each li in height & width ? or do you want long to split to 2 lines?

Comment: I was looking for a solution to split the "long" one into 2 lines. I'm still struggling with my code - the answer from ExpertSystem is working in the live Example but somehow I still couldn't get it in 2 lines. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the contents of the `<a>`s in a `<span>`, like:

```
<li><a href="#">
    <span><span>Very very very long Sub-Category 3</span></span>
</a></li>
```

Then in your CSS add something like this:

```
.supplier_top_link li ul li a span {
    width: 150px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and probably remove the "height" attribute of the `<a>`s to look nicer:

```
.supplier_top_link li ul li a {
    ...
    /* height: 28px;   <-- Remove this */
    ...
```

See, also, this **[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Txxkj/)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply but as mentioned above I still couldn't make it work. I checked your corrections and did the same - but since I'm tring to correct the code of someone who worked on this project before, the menu seams to have another class which is not in the CSS file I'm working on and I couldn't figure out yet...

Comment: @StefanWeiss: I used the code you provided to create the demo. If the code you are working on is different and you can't get it to work, why not post the actual code ?

Comment: Sorry if I made it confusing. The code I posted is the original one (copy/past). To keep it simple, I just replaced the categories with the word "category". I assume that the very complicated PHP structure of this multi-language project (3 other programers gave up on this already..!)  is causing some problems which I can't handle. I guess the alternative is to divide the long categoies in two lines manually.  Might there be a way to activate two seperate <li> at the same time to change in :hover status even the mouse is just on one of them? Thanks again for your time and interst.

Comment: If yu want to do it manually, you can simply put a `<br>` inside the `<a>`, e.g. `<a href="#">Very very very<br>long Sub-Category</a>`. I used your code and it worked, how on earth can it not work for you ?

Comment: It's a nightmare - believe me! I tried that before and just now again, it breaks the line as it should but doesn't show the rest of it in a second line. That's why I simply just split the whole category it in 2 <li> 's. But still couldn't solve how to get the hover effect for both of them at the same time. Any idea on that?

Comment: It will show it if you remove the `height = 28px` in CSS under `.supplier_top_link li ul li a` (as I mention in my answer above). Unless there is more CSS that you are not showing us :)

Comment: Finally - it works! You where right, about a second CSS class which I totally missed. It's more for a grounp of buttons rather than this specific ones and I didn't know that they're connected with the same class. Something so actually simple became such a headache... Thanks again for your help and interest - I appreciate it a lot :)